COMSOL Muliphysics - CubeSat - Orbital Thermal Load
I hope you are doing well,
I'm Working on project By using COMSOL to study CubeSat in (Obrital Thermal Load) Physics.
I need to extract the data in table or graph for each face of the cubeSat in terms of (Heat Flux Vs Time).

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post
